# sequence generator for Mybatis with MySql

Tags: mysql, ibatis, mybatis

I'm new to Mybatis, trying to implement Mybatis with spring support.

I have to insert a record into a table but is Ibatis has sequence generator like hibernate does?

If not have to do it manually, like sequence.nextVal? which I dont like.

Any suggestions around would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Got it resolved by using auto-increment for PK.

Answer (score 1):

If you declared the mappers by yourself, you must do like this:

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="com.your.app.Product">
    <selectKey keyProperty="id" order="AFTER" resultType="java.lang.Integer">
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
    </selectKey>
    INSERT INTO product (name, value)
    VALUES (#{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{value,jdbcType=DOUBLE})
</insert>
```

But, if you're using the MyBatis Generator, you can do that by using the `generatedKey` tag inside the table tag and it'll generate the mappers like you need.

Example:

```
<table tableName="product" alias="product">
    <generatedKey column="id" sqlStatement="MySql" identity="true" />
</table>
```